# i don't know why i get this warning "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\phpmvcfram/migrations/..'

Tags: php

this is my database.php file. and when i try to run 'php migrations.php' it echeos that warning of permission denied. The line line that is pointed at is the one with require_once.

```
public function applyMigrationsTable()
{
     $this->createMigrationsTable();
     $appliedMigrations = $this->getAppliedMigrations();

      $files = scandir(Application::$ROOT_DIR.'/migrations');
      $toApplyMigrations = array_diff($files, $appliedMigrations);
      foreach ($toApplyMigrations as $migration){
          if ($migration === '.' || $migration === '...'){
              continue;
          }

     
          require_once Application::$ROOT_DIR.'/migrations/'.$migration;
          $className = pathinfo($migration, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

          echo '<pre>';
          var_dump($className);
          echo '</pre>';
          exit;
      }


}





}
```

Comment: It means the account PHP is running under doesn't have permission to open the file. Check your filesystem permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using

```
if ($migration === '.' || $migration === '..'){
```

in place of

```
if ($migration === '.' || $migration === '...'){
```

Check the three dots comparison, I think you want to compare the two dots, meaning the parent directory, and this matches your question title, PHP is trying to require the parent directory as a script!